# Difference between dplyr:mutate and transform when using pmin and pmax?

Tags: r, dplyr

While trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24743130/269476), I encountered a difference between `mutate` and `transform` in what I expected to be equivalent operations.

```
# data
x <- data.frame(a=c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10),3),b=c(1:10,0,11:19,0))

#transform
transform(x,a=pmin(a,b), b=pmax(a,b))
   a  b
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  0  3
4  0  4
5  0  5
6  0  6
7  0  7
8  0  8
9  0  9
10 0 10
11 0  1
12 1 11
13 1 12
14 1 13
15 1 14
16 1 15
17 1 16
18 1 17
19 1 18
20 1 19
21 0  3

#mutate
libarary(dplyr)
x %>% mutate(a=pmin(a,b), b=pmax(a,b))
   a  b
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  0  3
4  0  4
5  0  5
6  0  6
7  0  7
8  0  8
9  0  9
10 0 10
11 0  0
12 1 11
13 1 12
14 1 13
15 1 14
16 1 15
17 1 16
18 1 17
19 1 18
20 1 19
21 0  0
```

Note the differences in lines 11 and 21. I suspect that `mutate` is mutating the data as it goes and therefore, `pmax` is not seeing the original data. Is this correct? Is it a bug, or by design?

Comment: you're correct, and it's by design (there's some discussion in the archives, I forget where).

Comment: @baptiste Thanks, I think I understand why now: to allow computed variables to be used in the same command, so the originals need to be referenced explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

It appears my suspicions are correct, and that it is by design to allow the use of computed variables immediately afterwards, eg:

```
data.frame(a=1:4,b=5:8) %>% mutate(sum=a+b, letter=letters[sum])
  a b sum letter
1 1 5   6      f
2 2 6   8      h
3 3 7  10      j
4 4 8  12      l
```

In order to replicate the expected behaviour from `transform` one needs to simply reference the variable directly:

```
x %>% mutate(a=pmin(x$a,x$b), b=pmax(x$a,x$b))
   a  b
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  0  3
4  0  4
5  0  5
6  0  6
7  0  7
8  0  8
9  0  9
10 0 10
11 0  1
12 1 11
13 1 12
14 1 13
15 1 14
16 1 15
17 1 16
18 1 17
19 1 18
20 1 19
21 0  3
```

Comment: Not explicitly about `pmin` and `pmax`, but you may read about this behaviour in the [dplyr vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html): `dplyr::mutate()` works the same way as `plyr::mutate()` and similarly to `base::transform()`. The key difference between `mutate()` and `transform()` is that mutate allows you to refer to columns that you just created [the 'a' column in your example]"

Comment: Could you please explain the use of %>% ?

Comment: Is there a typo: "In order to replicate the expected behaviour from transform one needs to ". You are referring to mutate, right ? Thanks for alerting to this difference.

Comment: @Anusha `%>%` is an implementation of piping using the `magrittr` package. I don't think there is a typo, I am replicating the behaviour of transform in mutate.

Comment: To replicate the expected output from transform you could actually use the x$ notation only for the second x$a, I think it makes it clearer.